# How to test if a UIControlEvents has been fired

Tags: ios, swift, selector, xctest, nsrunloop

I have a library implementing a custom `UIControl` with a method which would fire a `.valueChanged` event when called. I would like to test the method for that behavior.

**My custom control:**

```
class MyControl: UIControl {
    func fire() {
        sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
import XCTest

class ControlEventObserver: NSObject {
    var expectation: XCTestExpectation!

    init(expectation anExpectation: XCTestExpectation) {
        expectation = anExpectation
    }

    func observe() {
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
}

class Tests: XCTestCase {
    func test() {
        let myExpectation = expectation(description: "event fired")
        let observer = ControlEventObserver(expectation: myExpectation)
        let control = MyControl()
        control.addTarget(observer, action: #selector(ControlEventObserver.observe), for: .valueChanged)
        control.fire()
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1) { error in
            XCTAssertNil(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the `observe` method never gets called so the `expectation` is not fulfilled.

The question is: how can we test for `UIControlEvents` like in this case? Perhaps we need to force the runloop somehow?

EDIT 1:
Please note that since I am testing a library, my test target does not have any Host Application. The test above passes when the test target has a host application.

Comment: this is weird I have copied and pasted your code in a project I created and the expectation is fullfiled, test passed successfully.

Comment: Just realized that might because that I am testing a library. When I create another test target with a host application, the test above passes. @WilsonBalderrama

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Apple's documentation for UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol) states that:

> When a control-specific event occurs, the control calls any associated
>   action methods right away. **Action methods are dispatched through the
>   current UIApplication object**, which finds an appropriate object to
>   handle the message, following the responder chain if needed.

When `sendActions(for:)` is called on a UIControl, the control will call the `UIApplication`'s `sendAction(_:to:from:for:)` to deliver the event to the registered target.

Since I am testing a library without any Host Application, there is no `UIApplication` object. Hence, the `.valueChanged` event is not dispatched and the `observe` method does not get called.

Comment: Then how did you simulate the tap event in a library?

Comment: @User9527 I ended up created a simple Host App for my test suit

Comment: Would you be able to show how this was done @ThanhPham? I've got a similar question about UIButton [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58519479/2547229)

Comment: @Benjohn I created an app target, and in the test target's General settings screen, I made the app target the Host Application of the test target.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the observer object inside the test method. This means that as soon as the method completes it will be released from memory and hence is not called. Create a reference to the observer at class level in the `Tests` class as follows and it will work.

```
class Tests: XCTestCase {

    var observer: ControlEventObserver!
    func test() {
        let myExpectation = expectation(description: "event fired")
        self.observer = ControlEventObserver(expectation: myExpectation)
        let control = MyControl()
        control.addTarget(observer, action:#selector(ControlEventObserver.observe), for: .valueChanged)
        control.fire()
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1) { error in
            XCTAssertNil(error)
        }
    }
}
```

You will also need the `myExpectation` & `control` to be declared in the same way else that won't be called either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the objects are not released because I don't create any auto release pool. Also, I am testing a library so the test target doesn't have any Host Application. I've revised my question to reflect that.