# UIControl's sendActions doesn't work in Test target

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestexpectation

I'm trying to test that when `UITextField` sends `editingChanged` event special handler is invoked. So, for that purpose I simulate this event by `sendActions` method. But it doesn't work in Test target, all ok just in the project (Run mode - simulator).

I've written a small example:

```
class Strange {
    private let handler: () -> Void

    init(textField: UITextField, handler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.handler = handler
        textField.addTarget(self, action:#selector(textableValueChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc private func textableValueChanged() {
        handler()
    }
}
```

Here I want to see "test" print, but this handler isn't invoked after `sendActions` event. I've also tried with `expectation` but it didn't help me.

```
func testStrangeBehaviour() {
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Bla-bla")
    s = Strange(textField: textfield1) {
        print("test")
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    textfield1.sendActions(for: .editingChanged)
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5, handler: nil)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that the solution is https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856918/2294228. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found interesting category in Reactive Cocoa library. 
It helps me!
https://github.com/RACCommunity/Rex/blob/master/Tests/Helpers/UIControl%2BEnableSendActionsForControlEvents.swift