# UISlider addTarget and sendActions not working in UTs

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

When I run this code in a standard MVC project, all works fine: I can programmatically send actions to my UISlider.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50))
    slider.minimumValue = 1
    slider.maximumValue = 100
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderTouch), for: .touchUpInside)
    slider.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
}

func sliderTouch(sender: UISlider) {
    print("value: \(sender.value)")
}
```

Now for some reason, when I want to simulate Slider behaviors in my UTs, it's not working. here is the code:

```
func testSlider() {
    let slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50))
    slider.minimumValue = 1
    slider.maximumValue = 100
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderTouch), for: .touchUpInside)
    slider.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
}

func sliderTouch(sender: UISlider) {
    print("value: \(sender.value)")
}
```

`sliderTouch()` is never called in the UT case and from my understanding, sendActions is not `asnyc` and should directly call the action methods.

So why am I getting this behavior, and how can I solve this?

**Edit**: I also need it to work for other UIKit controls such as `UISwitch`, `UISegmentedControl`, `UIDatePicker` etc...

Comment: Do you wanna catch the touch?

Comment: In what way is this testing your component vs the UIKit-provided functionality of action dispatch? If you want to test your touch handling, you can just call the action method directly, like `sliderTouch(sender: slider)`. (It doesn't help clarify this, that your `testSlider` test function has no actual test assertions, so always passes.)

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman My use case is not the snippet above. I just wrote the snippet to show what the main problem is. I actually have a custom Slider in a library that reacts to an action dispatch in a certain way, and I want to test that the behavior is correct. I didn't write the assertions in the snippet above so I try not to confuse you and keep the problem clear :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a problem similar to yours when testing classes contained in a Framework target.

Here is an excerpt from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol):

> When a control-specific event occurs, the control calls any associated action methods right away. Action methods are dispatched through the current UIApplication object, which finds an appropriate object to handle the message, following the responder chain if needed.

When testing a classes in a framework **there is no `UIApplication` object** and thus the events can not be dispatched.

You can add a Host Application in your test target settings. If you do not have a host application, you can just create an empty iOS app and use that.

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856918/4294969).

**Update:**

Here is how to set a **Host Application**:

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

If there is no Application in the dropdown, simply create a new Target and use the **Application** > **Single View Application** template.

You are done and your tests should now work. There are no additional steps.

Comment: This is spot on! I will look into adding this Host application. If it works I'll mark as correct

Comment: Vasilii Muravev pointed out an approach in the comments of his answer, and seems to be adopted by ReactiveCocoa. It worked for me. Do you think your approach is better? Let me know cause I couldn't find an easy way to do it.

But in any case, your answer correctly gave me an answer for the "why it isn't working". Thanks a tons again.

Comment: Of course as with any topic there are benefits and downsides to each approach. Having said that, I think my solution should be the preferred solution as it does not rely on any additional code. Method swizzling is a very mighty thing but it comes with **a lot of pitfalls** if you don't fully understand what is going on. Also, to other team members working on the same code it may be very surprising to find themselves in a situation where a UIKit method does not actually do what it usually does because you exchanged it's implementation.

Comment: As for the "easy way to do it", I will add some screenshots to my post explaining what exactly you need to do.

Comment: I updated my post with additional details on how to set the Host application. If you have additional issues, let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144849/discussion-between-guy-daher-and-naglerrr).

Answer (score 2):

For swift 3:
https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/ae6ebb7725b3d5d33db039d456797c220720cb99/ReactiveCocoaTests/UIKit/UIControl%2BEnableSendActionsForControlEvents.swift

For Swift 2
https://github.com/RACCommunity/Rex/blob/master/Tests/Helpers/UIControl%2BEnableSendActionsForControlEvents.swift

Or try subclassing:

```
class TouchSlider: UISlider {
    var touchUpInsideHandler: ((TouchSlider) -> Void)?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchUpInsideHandler?(self)
        guard let touch = touches.first,
              let imageWidth = currentThumbImage?.size.width else {
            super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
            return
        }
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let newValue: Float = minimumValue + (maximumValue - minimumValue) * Float((location.x - imageWidth / 2.0) / (bounds.width - imageWidth))
        setValue(newValue, animated: true)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

Use `touchUpInsideHandler` for managing touches outside.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What I fear with this is that I don't only need to simulate a `UISlider`, but also a `UIDatePicker`, `UISwitch` and many others. That will be a lot of subclassing and boilerplate for a simple problem don't you think?

Comment: @GuyDaher you should concrete you question ;) `So why am I getting this behavior, and how can I solve this?`

Comment: You are right, my bad. I thought there was a solution that can be applied to all UIKit controls. I will edit the question, thank you for pointing that out and sorry again

Comment: @GuyDaher hm, it works for me:
```Test Case '-[BaseAppV2UnitTests.testTest testSleder]' started.
value: 1.0
Test Case '-[BaseAppV2UnitTests.testTest testSleder]' passed (0.004 seconds).```

Comment: I can't understand why it's not working on my side then. I am running the exact same code, and even put a breakpoint. Can't hit the breakpoint, nor see a print statement... weird

Comment: @GuyDaher look at it https://github.com/RACCommunity/Rex/blob/master/Tests/Helpers/UIControl%2BEnableSendActionsForControlEvents.swift

Comment: Awesome, that was super helpful. The link is actually Swift 2, so I found one that works for Swift 3 from ReactiveCocoa https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/ae6ebb7725b3d5d33db039d456797c220720cb99/ReactiveCocoaTests/UIKit/UIControl%2BEnableSendActionsForControlEvents.swift

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to reflect your new answer? Then I can help you edit it (since I got it working).