# XCTestCase of a UIButton tap

Tags: ios, uibutton, xctestcase

I am trying to unit test the wiring of button taps in a `UIViewController` but I'm finding these tests fail even though the code in the running app works fine.

I've simplified the failing test by removing the view controller and such leaving simply:

```
import XCTest

class ButtonTest: XCTestCase {

    var gotTap: XCTestExpectation!

    func test_givenButtonWithTargetForTapAction_whenButtonIsSentTapAction_thenTargetIsCalled() {

        gotTap = expectation(description: "Button tap recieved")

        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tap), for: .touchUpInside)

        button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)

        // Fails.
        wait(for: [gotTap], timeout: 0.1)
    }

    @objc func tap() {
        gotTap.fulfill()
    }
}
```

The the test does:

- Wires up an action to a button that fulfils a test expectation
- Taps the button using `button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)`
- Waits for the expectations.

The failure is:

> Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 0.1 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "Button tap recieved".

I don't want to use a UI test fo this. They are many orders of magnitude slower to execute, and a unit test should be ideal here.

## Questions

- Is this failing because the `UIButton` action sending requires some additional setup of the responder chain? Or a run loop that is not present here? Or something else? How can I set this up minimally in a unit test without instantiating a complete running app?
- I initially tried to synchronously test button taps without an expectation (this also didn't work so I thought I'd try asynchronously) – if you can help to get this working, please also indicate if action sending is synchronous or asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39851205/2547229) about control events has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856918/2547229) that control events require a `UIApplication` instance to send actions. Unfortunately the question doesn't indicate how this might be done.

There's also some code [here](https://github.com/RACCommunity/Rex/blob/master/Tests/Helpers/UIControl%2BEnableSendActionsForControlEvents.swift) that uses swizzling to patch the implementation of action sending on `UIControl` so that it doesn't delegate to `UIApplication`. It doesn't build with recent swift because it relies on overriding `initialize` – this might be fixable however.

The approach that I've taken is to implement an extension on `UIControl` for use in tests that provides a method `simulateEvent(_ event: UIControl.Event)` which goes like this:

```
extension UIControl {

    func simulateEvent(_ event: UIControl.Event) {
        for target in allTargets {
            let target = target as NSObjectProtocol
            for actionName in actions(forTarget: target, forControlEvent: event) ?? [] {
                let selector = Selector(actionName)
                target.perform(selector)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This could be refined to properly examine the selector and determine if the sender and event should also be sent, but it's a reasonable proof of concept and allows for button sending in `XCUnitTest`. I also feel it's non invasive and accepts the fact that a unit test is not running in a full application environment, so tests can't make use of full responder handling.