# How to programmatically invoke the action of a `UISwitch`?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController`, in an SPM package, with a `UITableView` with some simple cells - they're either detail disclosures or have a `UISwitch`.

I'm trying to write unit tests to confirm that when the switch in a specific row is toggled, the desired action is invoked. That action was provided by other code, so the cell configuration looks like:

```
let toggle = UISwitch(frame: .zero, primaryAction: UIAction(handler: { action in
    guard let toggle = action.sender as? UISwitch else { return }
    toggleAction(toggle.isOn)
}))
cell.accessoryView = toggle
```

(where `toggleAction` was one of many passed to the VC's `init`)

My test can find the row of interest, and the switch on it. It can modify the value via `.isOn`, but that doesn't trigger the action. I am aware of the need for a `UIApplication` in order for `.sendActions(for:)` to work, so am using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521288/325366), and confirm that it works for `UIButton`s. I have tried sending various events to the `UISwitch` (`.touchUpInside`, `.valueChanged`, `.primaryActionTriggered`), but none of them cause the registered action to be invoked. Is it possible?

Comment: if you have subclassed the UISwitch and store the primaryAction closure reference, you can set that during your unit tests as per your requirement, you can trigger the `toggleAction` closure for your tests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UISwitch` is a `UIControl`. Since you setup the switch with a `UIAction` for the primary action, you can call `sendActions` on the switch:

```swift
let switch = ... // a reference to the UISwitch from the table cell
switch.isOn = true // or false as needed
switch.sendActions(for: .primaryActionTriggered)
```

This will result in the switch's action being called which in turn calls your `toggleAction` method.

No reference to the `UIApplication` is needed for this.

---

Here is some sample code that demonstrates that using `sendActions` works for both `UISwitch` and `UIButton` and that it works whether the control is setup with a primary action or with a target/selector.

The following can be run in an iOS Swift Playground.

```swift
class Controls {
    func toggleAction(_ isOn: Bool) {
        print("toggleAction: \(isOn)")
    }
    @objc func toggleHandler(_ sender: UIControl) {
        print("toggleHandler: \(sender)")
    }

    lazy var toggle = UISwitch(frame: .zero, primaryAction: UIAction(handler: { action in
        guard let toggle = action.sender as? UISwitch else { return }
        self.toggleAction(toggle.isOn)
    }))
    lazy var button = UIButton(primaryAction: UIAction(handler: { action in
        self.toggleAction(false)
    }))
    lazy var other = UIButton(type: .custom)

    func doStuff() {
        other.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleHandler), for: .touchUpInside)
        toggle.isOn.toggle()
        toggle.sendActions(for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        other.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
        button.sendActions(for: .primaryActionTriggered)
    }
}

let x = Controls()
x.doStuff()
```

The output will be something like:

> toggleAction: true
> toggleHandler: <UIButton: 0x7fb77f406320; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000037e2fc0>>
> toggleAction: false

Comment: "true // or false as needed" ?? `switch.isOn.toggle()` always works

Comment: @matt True, but setting or toggling `isOn` is only tangential to the question and this answer.

Comment: This does indeed work. For tapping `UIButtons` in the same scenario, the linked solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521288/325366) *is* necessary, which lead me to expect it to be necessary for all interactions. Apparently that is not the case!

Comment: @Chris My answer works for UIButton as well. In either case, just make sure you pass the correct event that matches what action or target/selector has been setup for.

Comment: @HangarRash that was my initial expectation, but in this circumstance `UIButton` doesn't react. I've expanded my original question with example code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ah, it's not `UIButton` v.s. `UISwitch`, it's `.addTarget(_:action:for:)` v.s. `primaryAction:`

Comment: @Chris Its not. My answer works even if you use `addTarget`. I tested it and it works just fine. See my updated answer for sample code demonstrating a UISwitch and a UIButton with a primary action and a UIButton with a target/selector.

Comment: @HangarRash,thanks for persevering with this. If you create a new SPM and put your `Controls().doStuff()` in a unit test (the scenario I described), `toggleHandler(:)` is never called, whereas `toggleAction(:)` is called twice, as expected. As described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856918/325366) a `UIApplication` instance is required as part of how events are delivered. In an SPM scenario, there is no `UIApplication`.

Comment: I've para-phrased slightly there for comment-space reasons... This isn't down to `Controls` going out of scope prematurely - in my actual test the instance is retained and still the event isn't delivered.